# Trouble setting up config.php for local WAMPP server

Tags: php, wamp

Trying to work on developing our app on my local machine, so I installed WAMPP. Now I am having trouble getting all of the files to find eachother.

In our index.php file, we have:

```
// SET CONFIG
require dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php';

// SET AUTOLOADING
require ("App/Libraries/Callback/Loader.php");
```

And in the config.php, we have:

```
// SET ROOT PATH
define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'));
define('URL_ROOT', $rootConfig['url_root']);
define('DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Everything is located in: C:\wamp\www\callbackstaffing

App wont load correctly when I visit localhost/callbackstaffing/

What to do??!?!

Comment: I have to ask the silly question - any specific ports or are you using :80?

Comment: *App won't load correctly*. WHAT is the error?

Comment: Also, have you turned on error checking?

Comment: Are you using friendly urls, if so, how? Via php or htaccess?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Error: Uncaught fEnvironmentException

------------------------------

'{doc_root}\callbackstaffing\index.php(31): fCache->__construct('apc')

{doc_root}\callbackstaffing\App\Libraries\Flourish\fCache.php(223)

The apc extension does not appear to be installed' Also, not using friendly urls that I know of

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! APC wasn't installed...